# Fast Algorithm to find and element in a string

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I am newbie in algorithms and I needed to implement a fast search that make this. For example I have this sequence

```
seq ="1111111145555666672222222222222222221111";
```

and I have the element to search = "1";

I need an algorithm (as fast as can be able) to give me or the numbers of element ("1") exists in seq or the number of elements are different of "1" in sequence.

Comment: You just want us to provide the code?

Comment: Looks like homework. What have you tried? Show us some of your code.

Comment: Does the algorithm have to find all the "1" on the internet or just in the string?

Comment: @user3129195, It's a pretty straightforward task, you should try it on your own. Trying out things lets you discover cool stuffs sometime.

Answer (score 1):

From the sample string you've provided it looks like the string is essentially unsorted. In this case the only way to count the number of characters is it make one complete pass through the string.

A quick and dirty way to do this would be with the `Count` extension method:

```
int count=seq.Count(c => c=='1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex you can quickly find all matches and their indexes.

```
      string pattern = "1";
  string input = "1111111145555666672222222222222222221111";

  foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) 
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", 
                       m.Value, m.Index);
```

Comment: I believe the poster requested that the solution to their homework should be fast.

Comment: you could run the regex on the GPU to make it faster

Comment: LMAO. Could you provide code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear, but if you want to count how many "1" are in the string, just loop over the string.

```
int count = 0;
foreach(char c in inputstring)
{
    if(c.Equals('1'))
    {
      count++;
    }
}
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Count: {0}", count));
```